# Why isn't fastAPI making the database and returning the result here?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, fastapi, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

Long code ahead, kindly help out.

I am trying to create a point system for tweets. I have streamed tweets with #Python to a MySQL database and I am trying to create a points system for the same.

```
from typing_extensions import Self
import requests
import os
import json
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
bearer_token =  "$Bearer"#Getting tweet ids of specified user from database
ids=[]
class tweet_id:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def get_tweet_ids(self, name):
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                                database='twitterdb',
                                                user='root',
                                                password='pasword@123')

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            sql_select_query = """SELECT tweetid FROM twitterdb.StreamData WHERE username = %s"""
            # set variable in query
            cursor.execute(sql_select_query, (name,))
            # fetch result
            record = cursor.fetchall()

            for row in record:
                ids.append(int(row[0]))

        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print("Failed to get record from MySQL table: {}".format(error))

        """finally:
            if connection.is_connected():
                cursor.close()
                connection.close()"""

def create_url():
    tweet_fields = "tweet.fields=public_metrics"
    converted_list = [str(element) for element in ids]
    id_list = ",".join(converted_list)
    url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?ids={}&{}".format(id_list, tweet_fields)
    return url



def bearer_oauth(r):
    """
    Method required by bearer token authentication.
    """

    r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {bearer_token}"
    return r


def connect_to_endpoint(url):
    response = requests.request("GET", url, auth=bearer_oauth)
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Request returned an error: {} {} {}".format(
                response.status_code, response.text, ids
            )
        )
        return url
    return response.json()


def main():
        #def __init__(connect, append_to_database):
    #Self.connect = connect
    #Self.append_to_database = append_to_database
    def connect(tweetid, retweet_count, reply_count, like_count, quote_count):
        """
        connect to MySQL database and insert twitter data
        """
        try:
            con = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
            database='twitterdb', user='root', password='pasword@123', charset='utf8')

            if con.is_connected():
                """
                Insert twitter data
                """
                cursor = con.cursor(buffered=True)
                # twitter, golf
                query = "INSERT INTO Metrics (tweetid,retweet_count,reply_count,like_count,quote_count) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                cursor.execute(query, (tweetid,retweet_count,reply_count,like_count,quote_count))
                con.commit()
                

        except Error as e:
            print(e)

        cursor.close()
        con.close()

        return
    def append_to_database(json_response):
    #Loop through each tweet
        for tweet in json_response['data']:  
            # Tweet ID
            tweetid = tweet['id']
            # Tweet metrics
            retweet_count = tweet['public_metrics']['retweet_count']
            reply_count = tweet['public_metrics']['reply_count']
            like_count = tweet['public_metrics']['like_count']
            quote_count = tweet['public_metrics']['quote_count']
            connect(tweetid, retweet_count, reply_count, like_count, quote_count)
        url = create_url()
        json_response = connect_to_endpoint(url)
        append_to_database(json_response)
#function for connecting and inserting to database


#Function to calculate sum of points and display it
class summer:
    like_points=0
    reply_points=0
    total_rts=0
    rt_points=0
    total=0
    def sum_fun():

        try:
            con = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
            database='twitterdb', user='root', password='pasword@123', charset='utf8')

            if con.is_connected():
                cursor = con.cursor(buffered=True)
                def sum_rts():
                    cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(retweet_count) FROM twitterdb.Metrics")
                    sum1=cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
                    if sum1 is None:
                        return 0;
                    else:
                        return int(sum1)
                def sum_replies():
                    cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(reply_count) FROM twitterdb.Metrics")
                    sum2=cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
                    if sum2 is None:
                        return 0
                    else:
                        return int(sum2)
                def sum_likes():
                    cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(like_count) FROM twitterdb.Metrics")
                    sum3=cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
                    if sum3 is None:
                        return 0
                    else:
                        return int(sum3)
                def sum_qts():
                    cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(quote_count) FROM twitterdb.Metrics")
                    sum4=cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
                    if sum4 is None:
                        return 0
                    else:
                        return int(sum4)      
                like_points= (20*(sum_likes()))
                reply_points=  (100 * (sum_replies()))
                total_rts= (sum_rts() + sum_qts())
                rt_points = (300 * total_rts)
                total = (like_points + reply_points + rt_points)

                return total

                #print("Like Points:", like_points)
                #print("Reply Points:", reply_points)
                #print("Retweet Points:", rt_points)
                #print("Total Points:",total)
            # print(points)
                    


        except Error as e:
            print(e)

        cursor.close()
        con.close()

    
def clear():
    """
    connect to MySQL database and insert twitter data
    """
    try:
        con = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
        database='twitterdb', user='root', password='Mysql@123', charset='utf8')

        if con.is_connected():
            cursor = con.cursor(buffered=True)
            cursor.execute("truncate table twitterdb.Metrics")




    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    #cursor.close()
    #con.close()

    return
```

Furthermore I have created an API on FastAPI to trigger all the functionalities in the above script and get the outputs,like_points, reply_points,rt_points and total sent via an API.The API accepts the value username via a POST request and triggers the script.
API code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from metrics import tweet_id
from metrics import create_urls
from metrics import summer
import metrics
import uvicorn
from typing_extensions import Self

app = FastAPI()

class Username(BaseModel):
    username:str       
     
@app.post('/Username')
def Username(Username : Username):
    username=Username.username
    tweets_list = tweet_id(username)
    tweets_list.get_tweet_ids(str(username))
    metrics.clear()
    metrics.main()
    points=summer.sum_fun()
    return{points.total}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("api:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=5000, log_level="info")
```

I am unable to get the output and even though the request is completed I get `null` as the result. Why is that happening? Also, I am very new to a lot of this so code improvement suggestions and modifications are very welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have commented your `return` in `sum_fun()` function

```
            total = (like_points + reply_points + rt_points)

            #return total

            #print("Like Points:", like_points)
```

that's the reason `None` is returned when  `sum_fun()` is invocated.

Comment: I have edited that part and now the 'return total' part is un-commented. That haven't solved the issue and I am getting 'null' as reply now. I have been trying to debug this and discovered that the 'append_to_database' function isn't working. Atleast that's what it looks like. The variables like_count, reply_count, retweet_count and quote_count are stored to the database table named `Metrics` temporarily. But when I checked that table via mysql-workbench, it was empty. Could you please tell if there's anything preventing the script from inserting those variables into the database?
Thanks

Comment: You need to commit your `INSERT`s, or the changes will not be saved when the MySQL session is closed, try with `cursor.execute("commit")` or `con.commit()` before the connection is closed, details here: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html]. The `autocommit` connection argument is `False` by default, so you can set it when the connection is open `connect(host='...', autocommit=True)`

Or Set it whit the `autocommit` property  [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-autocommit.html]